# How can you find out what is the latest block number?

Tags: client, blockchain

When running a fresh client, or after not being connected for a while, the client takes some time downloading new blocks. How can you find out what is the target block number (the id of the newest publicly available block)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All these sites display the total block count:

- http://blockexplorer.com/
- http://bitcoincharts.com/
- http://bitcoinwatch.com/

BlockExplorer also has an [API](http://blockexplorer.com/q) that among other things lets you get [the latest block count](http://blockexplorer.com/q/getblockcount).

Answer (score 1):

[Block Explorer](http://blockexplorer.com/) displays the latest block.

Comment: Did anyone happen to implement a patch that integrates this into the official client? Should I post a feature request? (It seems like an obvious feature, so someone must have thought about it by now).

Comment: [Bitcoinwatch](http://bitcoinwatch.com/) also displays it. And [here](http://blockexplorer.com/q/getblockcount) is a more direct link for blockexplorer.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Biteasy.com](https://www.biteasy.com/blockchain/blocks) to find out.

The latest block is always visible at the top of the blocks list and it includes a date or if you need to find out via API then you can use the following API call which will return the latest one (in JSON format) since they are sorted by date (newest to oldest):

https://api.biteasy.com/blockchain/v1/blocks?per_page=1